# adding marker to arrayList lead to app crash

Tags: java, android

I am working on a map based application. It has an activity listed few request,  clicking on request will open a map activity where the distance between rider and driver will be shown. Upon clicking on a request app crash, but after repeated click it redirect to the map activity.

when app crash logcat says **`nullPointerexception`** on line:

```
markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLocation).title("your location")));
```

Here is the code:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Button acceptButton;
Intent intent;
ArrayList<Marker> markers = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_location);

    intent = getIntent();

    acceptButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.accept_button);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    RelativeLayout mapLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapRelativeLayout);
    mapLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            LatLng driverLocation = new LatLng(intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLatitude", 0), intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLongitude", 0));
            LatLng requestLocation = new LatLng(intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLatitude",0), intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLongitude",0));

            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLocation).title("your location")));
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(requestLocation).title("driverLocation")));

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (Marker marker : markers) {
                builder.include(marker.getPosition());
            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            int padding = 60; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);


            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
}

public void acceptRequest(View view) {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Request");
    query.whereEqualTo("username", intent.getStringExtra("username"));
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {

            if (e == null){
                if (objects.size() > 0){

                    for (ParseObject object : objects){

                        object.put("driverUserName", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                        object.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {

                                if (e == null){

                                    Intent directionIntents = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLatitude",0) + "," + intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLongitude",0) +
                                            "&daddr=" + intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLatitude",0) + "," + intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLongitude",0)));
                                    startActivity(directionIntents);

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like mMap is null. Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you get map async, your map loads later, so `mMap` is null when you use it.

To fix it, move this part of your code:

```
RelativeLayout mapLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapRelativeLayout);
    mapLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            LatLng driverLocation = new LatLng(intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLatitude", 0), intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLongitude", 0));
            LatLng requestLocation = new LatLng(intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLatitude",0), intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLongitude",0));

            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLocation).title("your location")));
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(requestLocation).title("driverLocation")));

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (Marker marker : markers) {
                builder.include(marker.getPosition());
            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            int padding = 60; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);


            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
        }
    });
```

To `onMapReady` method, after `mMap = googleMap;`. Like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    RelativeLayout mapLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mapRelativeLayout);
    mapLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            LatLng driverLocation = new LatLng(intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLatitude", 0), intent.getDoubleExtra("driverLongitude", 0));
            LatLng requestLocation = new LatLng(intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLatitude",0), intent.getDoubleExtra("requestLongitude",0));

            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(driverLocation).title("your location")));
            markers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(requestLocation).title("driverLocation")));

            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
            for (Marker marker : markers) {
                builder.include(marker.getPosition());
            }
            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();

            int padding = 60; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
            CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);


            mMap.animateCamera(cu);
        }
    });

}
```